# Replace a Solar Panel with a charging brick

Tags: voltage, current, solar-cell

I have a small solar lamp with a messed up solar panel. Now i want to replace the solar panel with a charging brick in order to charge my lamp. The question is what specification of charging brick should i go for so that i can charge my lamp. Below is a specification of the solar panel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkm1i.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solar panel specification looks close to a 9V, 300mA power supply. So a 'brick' type power supply with those specs should charge the battery in the lamp. Be sure to connect with the right polarity!

Comment: hhmmm 300mA is too small isn't it? Because even a phone charger normally comes with 5V 2A charging brick. this lamp weights about 2pounds

Comment: @Nanaba Is that weight all battery? Or a lump of metal to keep it down on the desk? Anyway, the solar panel's maximum short-circuit current rating is 309mA, and its maximum-power-transfer current is 286mA. Maybe it charges (charged) the lamp very slowly?

Comment: the 2pounds is not all battery. Please find below link for the exact type:https://johnkeane1.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/solar-light-2.jpg